# Sine & Cosine Word Problem

Tags: trigonometry

Problem: While a student was playing with their calculator they found that sometimes the answers produced from taking the sine and cosine of different angles were the same answer. The information below are some of the examples of when this occurs:

1. $\sin(55^\circ) = 0.819$ and $\cos(35^\circ) = 0.819$
2. $\sin(30^\circ) = 0.5$ and $\cos(60^\circ) = 0.5$
3. $\sin(15^\circ) = 0.258$ and $\cos(75^\circ) = 0.258$

Using your knowledge of trigonometry, explain why these calculations produce the same answer.

*Please reply in simple language, I'm a grade 9 student and will not understand complex answers.

Comment: $\sin(90^{\circ}-x) = \cos(x)$ <--- is this simple enough?

Comment: Can you put it into words, like what are you trying to say? That sin is 90 degrees minus x degrees is the same as cos is x degrees, and that's why they have the same answer?

Comment: @Simon Yes; for every $x$, its $\cos$ is the same as the $\sin$ of 90 degrees minus $x$.

Comment: @Simon Think in a triangle with 90 degrees in one of the angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### $$\sin(x^{\circ}) \equiv \cos(90^{\circ}-x)$$

where the $\equiv$ symbol means 'is equal for all values of $x$'.

---

This identity can be shown by using the addition formula for $\cos(A-B)$ or (less rigourously) by looking at the graphs of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$. You'll notice that the $\sin(x)$ graph is just the $\cos(x)$ graph shifted to the right by $90^\circ$.